# How do set the timeout on a wcf service caller in Delphi?

Tags: wcf, delphi, wcf-data-services, delphi-2010

I have a straightforward call to a wcf service hosted by iis I'm Delphi 2010

The operation being called on the service could take several minutes

What is the best way of avoiding a timeout error in Delphi?

I deliberately put a Thread.Sleep inside my WCF Service force it to wait for 31 seconds

After 30 seconds I got the error

Project  raised exception class ESOAPHTTPException with message 'The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation - URL:http://10.1.1.4/STC.WcfServices.Host/FlexProcurementService.svc - SOAPAction:http://navsl.stcenergy.com/FlexProcurement/FlexProcurementService/GetPassthroughSummaryGridReportData'.

This turned out to be a bug in Delphi 2010 which I have applied the patch for, so now I get the error operation timed out

```
function GetFlexProcurementService(const objServiceInfo: TWCFService; UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): FlexProcurementService;
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := objServiceInfo.WSDL
    else
      Addr := objServiceInfo.URL;
end;
if HTTPRIO = nil then
  RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
else
  RIO := HTTPRIO;
try
  Result := (RIO as FlexProcurementService);
  if UseWSDL then
  begin
    RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
    RIO.Service := objServiceInfo.Svc;
    RIO.Port := objServiceInfo.Prt;
  end else
    RIO.URL := Addr;
finally
  if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
    RIO.Free;
end;
```

end;

Paul

Comment: I need to avoid the timeout completely?

Comment: I was not at work when I sent that message, have now added the code and error

Comment: The error shown above is due to the bug in Delphi 2010

Answer (score 0):

```
uses wininet;
...

function SetTimeout(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer; NumSecs : integer) : boolean;
var
  TimeOut: Integer;
begin
  // Sets the receive timeout. i.e. how long to wait to 'receive' the response
  TimeOut := (NumSecs * 1000);
  try
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT,  Pointer(@TimeOut),  SizeOf(TimeOut));
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT,  Pointer(@TimeOut),  SizeOf(TimeOut));
  except on E:Exception do
    raise Exception.Create(Format('Unhandled Exception:[%s] while setting timeout to [%d] - ',[E.ClassName, TimeOut, e.Message]));
  end;
end;
```

In the RIO OnBeforePost:

```
procedure TEETOUpsertWrapper.OnBeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);    begin
  SetTimeout(HTTPReqResp, Data, 5 * 60);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this Chris  What units do I need for InternetSetOption and the constants?

Comment: wininet. I added to the answer for clarity.