# Delphi INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT Pointer error

Tags: delphi, pointers, runtime-error

i implemented the bwlow function to set INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT prior submitting to receive omething to avoid the timeout... this is working pretty well. 
This function is implemented in a second form, i call from my main form with a menu. 
When i close the second form, everything is ok. But when i close the main form, i get an error: Exception. Invalid Pointer...

if i dont call the function, i dont get the error... am stuck... anybody there to help me ?

```
function SetTimeout(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer; NumSecs : integer) : boolean;
var
  TimeOut: Integer;
begin
  // Sets the receive timeout. i.e. how long to wait to 'receive' the response
  TimeOut := (NumSecs * 1000);
  try
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT,  Pointer(@TimeOut),  SizeOf(TimeOut));
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT,  Pointer(@TimeOut),  SizeOf(TimeOut));
  except on E:Exception do
    raise Exception.Create(Format('Unhandled Exception:[%s] while setting timeout to [%d] - ',[E.ClassName, TimeOut, e.Message]));
  end;
end;


procedure TFmTestv2.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(
  const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
begin
  SetTimeout(HTTPReqResp, Data, 5 * 60);
end;
```

like described in this post

[How do set the timeout on a wcf service caller in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577304/how-do-set-the-timeout-on-a-wcf-service-caller-in-delphi)

best regards
Holger

Comment: I think `Pointer(@TimeOut)` can just be `@TimeOut`, although that probably won't fix your problem.

Comment: You are right... this doesnt fix it... :-(

Comment: @Holger why would you expect it to?

Comment: I didnt expect it, David... was pretty clear, that this is not my problem...

Comment: Golez just said that the cast was spurious.

Answer (score 0):

The most plausible explanation for an error relating to the code shown is that you are passing an invalid `HINTERNET` parameter. That's the first parameter you pass to the API function. My guess is that it's just something other than an `HINTERNET`. The fact that it is typed `Pointer` is a concern. According to the documentation this parameter must be either a valid `HINTERNET` or `NULL`. Make sure that it is. I see no evidence at all that the value of the `Data` parameter of the `HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost` event handler is an `HINTERNET`.

I also suggest that you check for errors correctly. Start by reading the documentation for each API call you make, and following the instructions for error checking. You certainly fail to check for errors in the code shown. You've copied somebody else's code that does it wrongly. That's a risk when you copy code. In this case the code you have copied ignores return values which are how errors are signaled, and instead traps exceptions that are never raised.

Comment: To be more concrete what i do:
The function logs into magento using Soap API V2 from Magento and receives the session id:
`code
    HTTPRio1.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost := HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost;
    mage := GetMage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortType(True, API_Path, HTTPRio1);
    session_id := magelogin(API_User, API_Key);
    mysession_id := session_id.result;
`

Comment: and after that i log out from the magento session.
The problem is, without calling the function for the timeout setting, i dont receive any error... and i dont receive the error in the window where i call this function... but when i close the main application.

Comment: You don't check for any errors so you don't know whether or not there are any.